# PayTM All-In-One SDK payment stuck on processing and delegates are not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, payment-gateway, paytm

I was trying to integrate Paytm payment sdk using the All-In-One SDK they provides. I was using the [SDK based integration](https://developer.paytm.com/docs/all-in-one-sdk/sdk-based-integration/) . But after payment is done, it gets stuck on a page with "Processing Payment" text. Even if the payment is done, it is not calling the `didFinish` delegate function. This issue only occurs when the payment is done using `openPaymentWebVC`, if we use paytm app directly everything works fine.

```
self.handler.openPaytm(merchantId: PayTmKeys.mId, orderId: payTmOrderId, txnToken: payTmTxnToken, amount:strPayment, callbackUrl: PayTmKeys.verifyUrl+self.payTmOrderId, delegate: self, environment: .production)
```

The delegate functions are as follows.

```
extension CAPaymentGatewayViewController: AIDelegate {
    
    func openPaymentWebVC(_ controller: UIViewController?) {

        if let vc = controller {                
            DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in
                self?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    func didFinish(with status: AIPaymentStatus, response: [String : Any]) {
        print("Response: \(response)")
    }
}
```

The callback URL used is

> https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=payTmOrderId

Comment: Hello Amal, Have you got the solution ? Same issue are coming on my end also.

Comment: @KanhaiyaSharma Not exactly. However I found a workaround to solve this. I will add it as an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried a lot to get a proper solution for this, but didnt get any. However I found a workaround solution.

First I looped through the paytm viewcontroller's subview to get the WKWebview and added an observer to know the url change in webview.

```
func openPaymentWebVC(_ controller: UIViewController?) {
        if let vc = controller {
            paytmPaymentController = vc
            DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in
                self?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: {
                    print(" super view type: \(type(of: vc.view))")
                    vc.view.loopViewHierarchy { (view, stop) in
                        if view is WKWebView {
                            /// use the view
                            print("This view is WKWebview")
                            if let wkview = view as? WKWebView {
                                print("Entered in column")
                                
                                wkview.addObserver(self!, forKeyPath: "URL", options: .new, context: nil)
                            }
                            stop = true
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

It will get called whenever the url changed in paytm webview. When I get the callback url(processing screen), I dismiss the paytm viewcontroller.

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if let key = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? NSURL {
            print(type(of: key))
            print("observeValue \(key)") // url value
            if key.absoluteString == "https://merchant.com/callback" {
                paytmPaymentController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

The next step is to verify the payment status using api from your backend using [this](https://developer.paytm.com/docs/api/v3/transaction-status-api/?ref=payments) api

Answer (score 0):

Kindly ensure you are sending the call back url in initiate transaction API while generating the txn token.